# Jmeter plugin webdriver sampler

Tags: browser-automation, jmeter, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, jmeter-plugins

JMeter web driver is used for measuring performance metrics of browsers, but it requires writing of scripts. Is there any way I could record these scripts?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment it is not possible to record these scripts. There is [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) project which can record browser actions and export the recording into several programming languages, however supported languages list doesn't include JavaScript. Besides Selenium IDE produces quite "dirty" code.

So I would suggest developing scripts from scratch. A lot of code snippets  for the most common actions mostly in Java are available over the web.

Reading [WebDriver JavaDoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) is a good start and [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for the most commonly asked queries followed by solutions.